# How to use ng-required with $touched?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I try to set an input as required if another input has changed. My need is to require confirm password if password has changed.

I use this on the input of confirm password but it is never required :

```
ng-required="userForm.Password.$touched"
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpagbW)

Another question : Is there a way to remove `ng-Model="user.ConfirmPassword"`? because ConfirmPassword is not necessary on my model "user", isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `name` property instead of `id`.

Also, this is no valid syntax:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="userForm.Password.$touched  userForm.Password.$error.required">Password is required</span>
```

It should be:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="userForm.Password.$touched">Password is required</span>
```

Then it will work just fine, as long as `Password` is the *name* of the input element, not the ID.

Comment: Ok, i need to use name instead of id. Could you reply to the second question?

Comment: @Troopers Of course you don't have to store the confirmed password on your user model. You can store it wherever you want. Instead of `user.ConfirmPassword` just use `ConfirmPassword`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `name` property, so you can't use form properties for Password and ConfirmPassword...
Also change AND to OR..

here is updated code

```
<form name="userForm" ng-controller="userController">
  <label for="Password">Set a password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" ng-model="user.Password" required />
  <span class="error" ng-show="userForm.Password.$touched">Password is required</span>
  <br />
  <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm the password:</label>
  <input name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" id="ConfirmPassword" ng-model="user.ConfirmPassword" ng-required="userForm.Password.$touched" />
  <span class="error" ng-show="userForm.Password.$touched || userForm.ConfirmPassword.$touched || userForm.ConfirmPassword.$error.required">Confirm password is required</span>
  <br/>
  <span>Password: {{user.Password}}</span>
  <br/>
  <span>Conform Password: {{user.ConfirmPassword}}</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, i need to use name instead of id. Could you reply to the second question?

Comment: If you wish to remove ng-model then why are you keeping the field and if keeping how do you want to use confirm password field?

Comment: Confirm password is requierd for validation purpose but not for business. So it should not be in the business model, isn't it?

Comment: Confirm password generally used when creating new accounts or when changing password, so if you're using it while logging in, that's not required. And for your question, if you remove ng-model then there is no point of keeping the field it's useless.